Compile kotlin at runtime and output the class file
I found this dependency, but couldn't find its API
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11")

I want to compile kotlin code at runtime and output a class file. What should I do

See also: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-vs-kotlin-compiler/3196 - it seems you only need kotlin-compiler dependency.

Also, if you download the command-line Kotlin compiler, and read the contents of the bin/kotlinc shell script, you'll see that it uses the same kotlin-compiler.jar file that you are referring to. See how it's used and figure out how to use it from your code.
